# Probability that two earth quakes are spaced at least 5 years between each other

Tags: probability, poisson-process

The problem is stated as:

> Alaska has over half of all earthquakes in the United States. In particular, earthquakes with magnitude>8 on the Richter scale occur in Alaska on average every
> 13 years. Suppose that these occur according to a Poisson process. Compute
> the probability that two consecutive such earthquakes are at least 5 years apart.

**My attempt:**

So, if we let $X(t)$ denote the amount of earthquakes with magnitude $> 8$ in time $t$, we know that $X(t)$ is a poisson distribution with intensity $\lambda = t/13$. Since the expected value $\lambda = 1$ for $t=13$.

What is sought, is $P(X(t) - X(0) = 2 | t \geq 5)$, and by the memoryless property, we can choose our time interval as $[0,t]$ without loss of generality.

Now, from this, we know that $X(t)-X(0)$ is also poisson distributed with intensity $t/13$, meaning we are essentially searching for $P(X(t) = 2 | t \geq 5) = 1 - P(X(t) = 2 | t < 5) = 1 - \sum_{t=1}^4 P(X(t)=2) = 1- \sum_{t=1}^4 e^{-t/13} \frac{(t/13)^2}{2!} $

It seems I've complicated things since my answer sheet tells me that it's $e^{-5/13}$, and I don't really see what steps I'm doing wrong. From the answer sheet, it almost sees like they substitued the $5$ inside some formula directly, but I can't see which one it is.

I'd be glad if anyone could clarify the steps in order to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: X(t) - X(0) = 2 means you have two earthquakes within a time window t which is 5 years in your case, which is not what the question requires…

Comment: I'd say the problem was ambiguously phrased.  On its face, it seems to be asking for the probability that, out of a string of earthquakes, there is at least one pair separated by at least $5$ years...but, as we are told nothing about that string there is no hope of answering that. If, instead, the problem is simply asking "given that an earthquake just happened, what is the probability that the next one doesn't occur for at least $5$ years" then the official answer is correct.

Comment: Also, it is trivial if you know that the waiting time of a Poisson process follows an exponential distribution

Answer (score 1):

Your conditional probability:

$P(N(t)=2|t\geq 5) = 1-P(N(t)=2|t< 5)$ does not seem correct. It should be $1 - P(N(t)\neq 2 |t \geq 5)$. It would be difficult for you to find a solution with this approach since you are conditioning on $t$ here, but the question asks you to find a probability that over some value of $t$ i.e. $t \geq 5$.

You already established that we can simply find the probability with respect to $X(t)-X(0)$ by memoryless property, and $X(0)=0$. Instead, let $T_2$ denote the time the second quake arrives and $T_1$ denote the time the first quake arrives with $T_1 < T_2$. Then the probability that two consecutive quakes are 5 years apart is the same as asking $P(T_2-T_1 > 5)$, and by that memorylessness property, we can also as $P(T_1-T_0 > 5)$.

We have defined the zero-th arrival time, or the arrival of the zeroth object as $T_0 = 0$. So our problem reduces down to $P(T_1 > 5)$. This simply means the first quake does not arrive until after $t=5$, which we can model with $X(t) = 0$ for at least up to $t=5$. Since $X(t)$ is monotone non-decreasing on $t$, we just need to find $P(X(5) = 0)$. By property of homogeneous Poisson processes, $X(5) \sim Pois(5 \lambda)$ so $P(X(5)=0) = \frac{e^{-5/13}(5/13)^0}{0!} = e^{-5/13}$.